# Hibernate : Help in resolving exception org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am using Hibernate as ORM for my project. I use mysql Database
I have a table "Products" inside DB "catalog".
I have put the @Table(name="Products",schema="catalog") annotation for the entity Products in my application.

However when I try to run the application I get the below exception. Can you please help me resolve this issue?

```
Exception:  
        Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table:Products
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1281)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:155)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:508)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1769)
        at org.eros.purchase.db.utils.HibernateUtil.configure(HibernateUtil.java:17)
        at Test.main(Test.java:14)
```

Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

Comment: The missing table identified is not Products but Users.  Look at that mapping and table.

Comment: Exception is talking about different missing table - Users

Comment: Check your mapping class where you have mapped as user, which is not present in Database

Comment: I corrected the description. Actually I'm looking for "Products" itself.

Comment: Try by removing schema

Comment: I removed the schema but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 3):

Please update your hibernate.cfg.xml file by adding this property

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
or 
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same exception from hibernate. In my case, it was because the database user was not properly authorized to see the tables. The tables were definitively there on the database.

After I assigned the roles *db_datareader* to the user for this database it worked.

However, in another case, where the tables weren't actually there, I got exactly the same exception from hibernate. I cases where the tables are there, I think hibernate might show no more information because of security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I think your mapping is referring to `User` table which is actually not in database. .
so check your xml mapping of hibernate

Comment: My mapping is looking for "Products" itself.

Comment: I have fixed the description of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.mypackage;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;//first check two annotations belong to right package
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Products",schema="catalog")
    public class Products{

    //entity attributes
    }
```

//second check mapping file (if use)i.e register Products class with right spelling 
// or third check Hibernate util if we are register mapping class like this

```
public class CustomHibernateUtil{


private static Configuration getConfiguration(){

configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Products.class);
return configuration;

}
}
```

Comment: I have specified the mapping in "hibernate.cfg.xml". Below is the mapping tag in the "hibernate.cfg.xml" file 
        <mapping class="org.xyz.Products"/>